# How to define a const struct to make a consant

Tags: c, header, typedef, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to make a const struct so I can use is values as constant

For this purpose I have write this code:

```
typedef struct __PIN{
    GPIO_TypeDef GPIO;
    uint16_t pin;
}__PIN;

const struct __PIN PA1 = {.GPIO=GPIOA,.pin=GPIO_PIN_5};
```

But When I compile it prompt me whit the following error:
"multiple definition of 'PA1' "
but it's only defined in this file!
in fact the its said that is defined first in the same file and line that prompt the error:

.../CUSTOM/GPIO_custom/GPIO_lite_s.h:27: multiple definition of `PA1'; .../CUSTOM/GPIO_custom/GPIO_lite_s.h:27: first defined here
what is going on?
should I do this on a different way?
additional info:

-this is the header of a library that Im making, I want this constant value to be accesible to all files that include this header.

-Im programming on a STM32 board (STM32F411CEU6) using STM32CubeIDE 1.10.1

-I included the main.h so I can use the uint8_t like variables

-this files is currently being included in 2 files, main.c and another .c file, deleting its include in either of those files seems to fix the problem, but I don't know why.

any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If the header file is included in more than one translation unit then you have multiple definitions of the object.

Comment: A quick workaround is adding `static` storage specifier

Comment: You're [obviously] using a `.h` to define the struct _and_ provide a _definition_ for `PA1`. You're doing a `#include` for that `.h` in _multiple_ `.c` files. In the `.h` change: `const struct __PIN PA1 = {.GPIO=GPIOA,.pin=GPIO_PIN_5};` into `extern const struct __PIN PA1;` [a _declaration_] and put the `const struct __PIN PA1 = {.GPIO=GPIOA,.pin=GPIO_PIN_5};` _definition_ into _one_ `.c` file.

Comment: thanks to everyone I undestand the phenomena now and I was able to fix it